# What's the difference about LinkedList?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

```
public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null && current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.val == current.val) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

This is a program that delete duplicated value node from LinkedList(e.g. [1,1,2,3,4,4]→[1,2,3,4]).

I am wondering why "current.next = current.next.next;" delete "current.next" with "current.next.next" and "current = current.next;" move pointer to "current.next".

For me, Looks like both are "delete program".

Comment: It basically replaces the reference for the next node with the next next node.
Then that node will have no reference from any object and the garbage detector will remove it.

Comment: `current =` will never change the list itself. `current` is a variable, and you only change the contents of a variable. To change something in the list you'll need to assign to some *property*.

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy to understand ,let me take a picture for you.

```
//this means No1 Node.next is forward to No3 Node,then No2 Node is remove
current.next = current.next.next;
//this means No1 Node reference is forward No2 Node,can't change No1 Node next reference
current = current.next;
```

the picture will tell your 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I understood it completely.